# Why do two confidence intervals only overlap when their difference $(\theta_1 − \theta_2) \pm z(SE_1 + SE_2)$ includes 0?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, overlapping-data

I am able to check if the interval contains 0 which I can find out by just plugging numbers into the above formula but I am curious as to why this interval containing zero means that the two CI's of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ overlap.

Comment: Because the answer comes down to the meaning of subtraction, one wonders what you are really trying to ask.  Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they overlap, there is a number $\color{blue}x$ from their intersection, i. e.

$$\color{blue}x \in \theta_1 \pm z(\text{SE}_1)\\
  \color{blue}x \in \theta_2 \pm z(\text{SE}_2)$$

By subtracting them, we obtain

$$\color{red}0 \in (\theta_1 - \theta_2)\pm z(\text{SE}_1 + \text{SE}_2)$$

(since $\color{blue}x - \color{blue}x = \color{red}0$).

---

*Note:*

I used the shortened notation; the expanded one is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\ \theta_1 - z(\text{SE}_1) \le\, &\color{blue}x \le \theta_1 + z(\text{SE}_1)\\
  \theta_2 - z(\text{SE}_2) \le\, &\color{blue}x \le \theta_2 + z(\text{SE}_2)\\
\hline
(\theta_1 - \theta_2) - z(\text{SE}_1 + \text{SE}_2) \le\, &\color{red}0 \le (\theta_1 - \theta_2) + z(\text{SE}_1 + \text{SE}_2)
\end{aligned}
$$